# Jquery Mobile UI or HTML,CSS, Which one to use?

Tags: jquery-mobile, user-interface, web, mobile-website

We are starting a mobile web development. We are into retailing business where we want to list all the menus and stuff available inside a mobile website. I have explored frameworks available on the web. I have seen some examples designed through Jquery Mobile UI and then I compared those with native apps, native apps look and feel is way better than what we can design through Jquery Mobile UI.

I believe we can achieve better look and feel using HTML and CSS for mobile web but we will miss all those effects in jquery mobile. Can somebody please validate my thought. For achieving good look and feel, Which one should we prefer, Jquery Mobile UI or custom development  using HTML and css ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't have to be an either or proposition.

There is a [Download Builder](http://jquerymobile.com/download-builder/) for JQM that allows you to download just the parts that your want using it you can for example just exclude the *listmenu*, or you can exclude all the widgets and just use JQM for the page transition effects or touch events..

Alternatively you always have the option of telling JQM [not to style](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/forms/forms-all-native.html) a specific section of your code, so you can just tell JQM not to style your lists or whatever and then use your own custom HTML and CSS for those parts.

Another option, you can use the classes that JQM uses for its widgets to add some custom styling, obviously you end up with the least customization this way but you can also still make use of the different methods and events that JQM provides with its widgets.